# Is it appropriate to ask colleagues for their mobile numbers on the first working day?

Tags: professionalism

Asking for a phone number right away might be too personal. Should I ask for their phone numbers on the first day, or wait until we really need to contact each other on mobile?

Comment: I have a feeling this is going to be a question where the answer is... it depends.

Comment: Seems like the core of the question is "are there any cases where it is *inappropriate*?" because certainly there are times where it *is* appropriate.

Comment: What do you need their mobile number *for*?

Comment: Why would you need the mobile phone number?  Is this a company mobile or a personal mobile?  Is that not something that is published in the company directory?  This question is too broad for a good answer.

Comment: No. Unless it is of course a business mobile used for line of business. No harm in asking in the case of business mobile, they can always say no.

Comment: Seems like it would *drastically* be different for different types of companies, different fields of work, and on different personal levels.  But, in all cases I would say *no*, and not ever.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Any personal details (i.e. personally owned mobiles) in my opinion should not be asked for, they should be given. I would expect it normally to be given/exchanged when a level of trust has been established between the individuals concerned and where they consider it ok to move from a professional relationship to a more personal one.

In this case I agree with Michael in that if it comes up that either party needs to contact one another outside of work then they will jointly agree to exchange their numbers. However, having this need on the first day of work seems highly unlikely to me (of course there are always exceptions). And to be honest, I would find it a bit weird (and creepy to be fair) if someone I just met was asking me for my own personal number after only just starting at the company we worked for.

Wait until you have gotten to know the person/people a bit better. When you have, the exchange of numbers will just happen naturally.

Comment: What if the OP needs to get a hold of them to do their job and it can not wait until his coworker reports for work? Someone's life could be on the line but he should wait until then even though that might cause a loss of life just because he just started in the position?

Comment: @Chad: If you're a new employee and not having a co-worker's mobile number can get someone killed, then yes, ask for it. Did you have a particular scenario in mind?

Comment: @Chad of course there are exceptions and in your case it seems to be an exception that is closely related to a work related need.  However your example sounds pretty extreme.  However if it's someones life on the line I would hope there's not many people out there that would have an objection to being contacted no matter how someone got their number, be it mobile or home.

Comment: My problem is the answer states it as though it is always wrong.  This is a bad question and while your answer covers the obvious you do not know why the OP needed the phone number so you through a dart at the board for the number that was easiest to hit.  This makes this a bad answer to me.

Comment: @Chad - Your point makes no sense.  How can something at work be life threating?  If they are in a field where that is possible, there are official means to go through, to get into contact them ( i.e. a doctor on call ).

Comment: @Chad If the OP needed numbers for a life-threatening situation on his first day of work, he would be given them on his first day of work, and not be posting to workplace.SE wondering if it would be bad form to ask for them.

Comment: @Chad if the person and their work are so important they have to be reachable outside of work hours, the company should supply him/her with a mobile phone for that purpose and distribute its number to those who have a need to know. I doubt a 1-day hire would be among those people.

Comment: @jwenting - I agree they should.. but have you ever started a position and someone forgot to give you something important that you need to do your job?  It does happen.  Often in your first few days you are handed off to several different people and sometimes those people assume someone else will give you that information.

Comment: @Ramhound - The op could be on a construction site... lots of things are life threatening there.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to break this down slightly differently:

**Company Contact Information**

You should ask for how to find it *for anyone* on the first day.  That includes - email, IM, landline phone, cell phone.  Discussion should include appropriate uses for this information (for example, is someone "on call" each night?  Is there a time that is too late?  What constitutes an emergency?).

Old school places will keep a list of this information, more modern places roll it into signatures, directory systems, or profiles.

The nature of any of these forms of communication is they are provided by the company with the expectation that every employee be able to use it for every other employee.

**Personal Information**

Most of the folks I know if in corporate America (mileage varies in other countries) - have two phones - one for home and one for work.  I knew a few old school folks who only carry a work phone, and a few underfunded folks who only carry a personal cell.  But most folks I know intentionally separate home and work life this way... and in some cases it is mandated by their work.

Asking for personal information varies significantly from culture to culture.  Here in Boston, I would be reluctant to ask a coworker for personal information unless we had clearly formed a personal bond.  That would be indicated by having made several arrangements to meet up outside of work at purely social, non-work-sponsored endeavors.  Not necessarily anything romantic, but definitely a relationship that has transcended work.

In general, to stay on the safe side, I'd be more likely to offer my own cell than ask for someone else's.  Especially if there is any doubt.

This is true for any personal information - home email, personal mobile, social network identity, home address.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you (think you) need a colleague's cell-phone number?  If your job involves possibly dealing with a problem in off hours and needing help, then the company should have a procedure in place for that already (emergency number, rotating beeper, cell-phone numbers in an employee directory, etc).  If that's the case, follow the company procedure.

If it's for any other reason, then you probably don't *really* need that information and should not ask for it on the first day.  If the person has a company-issued cell phone then it's appropriate to ask for that number the first time it seems plausible that you'll actually need it.  (But again, it might already be in a directory.)  If you're asking about a personal cell-phone number, don't; if your co-worker offers it then that's fine, but divulging this information should not be expected.  People should have a reasonable expectation of not being called, on personal phones, for business at all hours.

Answer (score 3):

No.

If it is generally the case that employees need to contact each other outside business hours, then there should be some sort of internal directory (wiki page, etc.) that has as much personal information as the employees are willing to share.  Asking for access to that on your first day would be perfectly appropriate.

If a new employee were to request this information on his/her first day, I would be concerned that he/she was looking to extend my work-time beyond what was established.  Unless this person is my new boss, I'd be hesitant.

There may be an exception for some cases -- if you were hired to establish 24 hour support for a product that never had any real formalized support.  Even so, I suspect you could wait until Day 2 to start collecting this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you will need to contact them outside the office you would need it for that.
However I would not ask for it.
If they want you to be able to call them they need to give you the number.
Let them do their job and you can focus on yours.

Comment: For a personal phone number, I agree (and I don't give mine out to coworkers absent a real need).  If it's a company-issued phone, that number should be available publicly within the company, and might already be in the employee phone directory.

Comment: What if the OP needs to get a hold of them to do their job and it can not wait until his coworker reports for work? Someone's life could be on the line but he should wait until then even though that might cause a loss of life just because he just started in the position?

Comment: @Chad In this case, the coworker should have a company-issued phone and be on call.

Comment: @Chad, what did people in that situation do before cell phones?  If you're in that kind of job, your employer should already have an emergency procedure in place.  So you follow it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio your comment seems like the closest thing to a real answer for me.  But this is a bad question and the answers are guesses that do no consider why the OP would want the number.

Comment: @Chad, thanks.  And yeah, I didn't post it as an answer because there are so many unknowns here, but maybe I should.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't ask for their personal contact no. on the very first day, except if someone just joined with me and we had a good talk already. In one of my last office, I was approached by my senior to take contact no. of immediate superior and HR, so that in case of any emergency I can contact them. However I don't think it's a common practice.
Anyways your colleagues will exchange the no. when they feel comfortable with you. You don't need to approach them first.

Answer (score -2):

If you are in a workplace where having each others' contact information is important, then that contact information should be stored in a directory that everyone has access to.  If there isn't already a culture of this, however, it can be very hard to establish one.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is getting downvotes and votes for deletion. Anyone mind explaining their reasoning?